# How to use AJAX and jQuery to retrieve WordPress page content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'll try to break this down to make it easy to understand what I want.

Basically,  I have a wordpress site with a lot of pages. What I want to do is have one page called "Work" and then on that page I have a sub-menu with links to the pages titled "Videos", "Audio", "Writing", and "Design".

Now what I want to happen is when you click on any of those links the content for those pages replaces the content on the page. Obviously the header, footer and navigation wouldn't change though.

From what I gathered, I'll need to use AJAX to do this. The reason being is that I want those pages to be their own separate pages back in WordPress. So that when I go and edit the "Audio" page, only the content for that page is changed.

I am a complete noob when it comes to php, ajax, jQuery, and Javascript. So if anyone can break it down for me to understand that would be awesome.

What I've gathered so far is that I need to just refresh a container that will hold all of the information/content.

For example:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <!-- Each one of these will change the content below when clicked-->
        <a href="#"><li>Nav item 1</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Nav item 2</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Nav item 3</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content-here">
    </div>
</div>
```

It's just that I have no idea how to do that. All I can find are snippets of Ajax but since I've never used it before, I don't know where it goes or anything like that.

Comment: i dont recommend doing this with ajax, just make them regular pages inside wordpress

Comment: If you do go with Ajax though, here's a decent tutorial on how to implement it with nonces and the like using wordpress's API http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Dagon I am planning on making them pages in wordpress. My question was how to get them to appear "inside" another worpress page when the links are clicked but not redirecting to the separate pages.

Comment: so why ajax at all? what do you gain?

Comment: @Dagon Because I only want the content in one of the divs to change. And from what I have read you need ajax to do that. Since I am basically wanting to only refresh one part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more handy for the dynamic  tag click

```
<script>
(function(){
    var index = {
        init: function(){
            //you could change the selector what ever you want to select
            //the selector provided select all anchor tag with href="#"
            $(document).on('click', "a[href='#']", this.exe_thisfunction);
        },
        exe_thisfunction: function(e){
            var yourdata = '';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sample.php',
                data: yourdata, // this is optional
                method: "post",
                success: function(data){
                    //success do what ever you want
                    //the data is the content of the url requested
                    $('#page-content-here').html(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    index.init();
})();
```

Take note. you could used only a jQuery before you include the jQuery library first.

#### Sample.php

```
<?php
echo "Content fetch!";
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement this into what I have and see what I get out of it :)

Comment: You could always debug your code if the url is not found. Cheers!

to debug using chrome just Use the keyboard shortcut Command + Option + J (Mac) or Control + Shift + J (Windows/Linux).

Comment: And you could always use the cdn of jQuery library

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

include that right before the jQuery code

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be the following

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <!-- Each one of these will change the content below when clicked-->
        <a onclick="$('#page-content-here').load('url-to-whatever');"><li>Nav item 1</li></a>
        <a onclick="$('#page-content-here').load('url-to-whatever-2');"><li>Nav item 2</li></a>
        <a onclick="$('#page-content-here').load('url-to-whatever-3');"><li>Nav item 3</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content-here">
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember that the #page-content-here div will be filled with the entire page requested - not just the content of that page. So this method is not recommended but should give you an idea of what is required.